# Keyword xsl:eval may not be used in namespace http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

How to add the two name sapce in one xsl. as xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"> is not supporting in eval and
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/TR/WD-xsl"> is not supporting "variable"
and I have to use eval and variable both in my xsl.

This is xsl file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<!--<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/TR/WD-xsl">-->
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"   xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="/">
<xsl:eval>calculPercent(this)</xsl:eval>
```

How to add both namespace in xsl please help.

Answer (score 0):

Use a second namespace prefix:

```xml
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                              xmlns:xsl2="http://www.w3.org/TR/WD-xsl">
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl2:eval>calculPercent(this)</xsl2:eval>
```